# Perl Regex - Print the matched value

Tags: regex, perl

What is the perl regex to print the matched value? For eg I want to print `195` from this string

```
"2011-04-11 00:39:28,736::[main]::INFO (Main.java:73) Test.Main::main() Total Successful Transactions = 195".
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use parentheses in regex to capture substrings. The captured groups are stored in $1, $2, and so on. Example:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

or, somewhat shorter:

```
while (<>) {
    print "$1\n" if /Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/;
}
```

You can also make use of the fact that the match operator (`//`) in list context returns a list of what was matched by groups:

```
$\ = '\n'; # Output newline after each print.
while (<>) {
    print for /Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/;
}
```

Which lets you write a compact one-liner (the `-l` option automatically adds newlines to each print, among other things):

```
perl -lne 'print for /Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/'
```

Answer (score 15):

Just wanted to reframe the previous answers a bit differently; note that in this case:

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /Xy = 3/;'
1
```

... we get 1 being printed out - as in "yes, I got a match". If we want to return the matched text portion, as [@markusk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5617355/277826) pointed out, "*use parentheses in regex to capture substrings*":

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/;'
Xy = 3
```

However, note that you may have a problem concatenating strings with this idiom, when capturing:

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /Xy = 3/ . "\n";' 
1 # OK
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/ . "\n";' 
1 # NOT OK
```

... so probably better to keep things separate in that case:

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/ ; print "\n";'
Xy = 3 # OK again
```

However, if we want to capture "something", say a digit - then, since we use parentheses, we automatically return just that match with this idiom (not the entire "searched for" string):

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /Xy = (\d)/ ; \
print "\n";'
3
```

... thus, to capture the searched string in its entirety, we should wrap it again in parentheses:

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /(Xy = (\d))/ ; \
print "\n";'
Xy = 33
```

.... but, we don't get what we expect, because now there are two matches, `$1` and `$2`; and apparently the idiom "`print $str =~ /.../`" outputs all matches (in this case, "`$1$2`").

So to get just the searched string in this nested matches case, we now *have* to explicitly specify only `$1`:

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; $str =~ /(Xy = (\d))/ ; \
print "$1 \n";'
Xy = 3
```

EDIT oct 2013: Via [Assign one of multiple regex matches to variable as Perl one-liner (dereference array?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446752/assign-one-of-multiple-regex-matches-to-variable-as-perl-one-liner-dereference) - also this can be done for a one liner:

```
$ perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; \
print ( ( $str =~ /(Xy = (\d))/ )[1] ); print "\n";'
3
```

... however, note the need for a second enveloping set of parentheses for the `print` to work directly with the regex returned (anonymous?) array.

Finally, in a multiline context, make sure to first "slurp" the entire file/text into a single string; then use the `/s` (single line mode = newline is matched) and `/g` (global/multiple matches) - and finally, make sure the match expression is in a `while` loop, so as to iterate through all the matches:

```
$ echo "some data
IN
123
OUT
some more data
 is about to follow:
IN
256
OUT
done with data
out" | perl -e '$str = do { local $/; <> }; while ($str =~ /(IN(.*?)OUT)/sg) { print "$1\n"} '

IN
123
OUT
IN
256
OUT
```

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: Slurping the entire file can be expensive for large inputs. An alternative is to use the range operator: `perl -ne 'print if /IN/../OUT/'`

Answer (score 10):

How about just:

```
print $string =~ /Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/;
```

You rarely actually need to use `$1` and friends.

Answer (score 5):

```
/(\d+$)/;
print $1;
```

I guess you just want the number `195`. Right?

Answer (score 4):

The command line version of the accepted answer by [@markusk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5617355/277826) is quite compact:

```
perl -ne '/Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/ && print "$1\n";'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $str = '"2011-04-11 00:39:28,736::[main]::INFO (Main.java:73) Test.Main::main() Total Successful Transactions = 195".';

$str =~ /Total Successful Transactions = (\d+)/;
print $1;
```

195 will be stored in $1

Answer (score 2):

Check for digits at the last just before `"` and `.`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = q{"2011-04-11 00:39:28,736::[main]::INFO (Main.java:73) Test.Main::main() Total Successful Transactions = 195".};
my ($number) = $string =~ m{ (\d+) " \. \z}x;

print "Matched number: $number\n" if defined $number;
```

Comment: Should check if match failed (setting $number to undef).  Also, you say "at the last" but don't implement that.

Comment: _[daxim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46395/daxim)_: Thank you. _[ysth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth)_: Thank you for letting me know. It was a miss. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
if ("2011-04-11 00:39:28,736::[main]::INFO (Main.java:73) Test.Main::main() Total Successful Transactions = 195" =~ /(\d+)$/) {
    print $1;
}
```

Once you match, the matched groups become available as $1..$n.

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to say print the value(number) where "Successful Tranaction" is present in the string.