# Perl Command Line Print - Test Regexp at Command Line

Tags: regex, perl, powershell

I'm very new to Perl and I'm trying to figure out just how to get this thing to work.

I found an example in this thread: [Perl Regex - Print the matched value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617314/perl-regex-print-the-matched-value)

Here is the example I'm trying to work with:

```
perl -e '$str="the variable Xy = 3 in this case"; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/;'
```

I've tried running it using cmd, but that produces this error:

"Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1."

When I run it in powershell nothing happens.

My ultimate goal is to set a variable at the command line, run a regexp find (and sometimes replace), and to print the result. This way I don't have to write a script every time I write a regexp pattern.

I've tried using the debugger, but nothing happens when I do this after setting the variable:

```
print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to put your statements inside a Perl script on a windows environment because you will need the double quotes for most of your Perl stuff, but escaping on the command line gets messy eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I figured it out for powershell. I had to escape the double quotes.

```
perl -e '$str=\"the variable Xy = 3 in this case\"; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/;'
```

And the same goes for cmd except that I had to replace the single quotes with double quotes since single quotes aren't a string delimiter there.

```
perl -e "$str=\"the variable Xy = 3 in this case\"; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/;"
```

Comment: I would change the string definition to qq{} instead of "" to avoid having to escape.  perl -e "$str=qq{the variable Xy = 3 in this case}; print $str =~ /(Xy = 3)/;"